# MassTransit bypass retry policy when non transient error occurs

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

What is the guidance to short circuit retry policy on a non transient error.

**Scenario.**

Using MassTransit v3 attached to RabbitMq.
A simple retry policy try 5 times setup in the pipeline.
In the Consume for the message, a non recoverable error occurs,  rather than throwing an exception and retrying another 4 times I'd like to  move this message to the error queue.

Comment: Ok looks like this is how.  var retryPolicy = new ExponentialRetryPolicy(
                    filter: new PolicyExceptPolicyExceptionFilter(typeof(SchemaValidationException)), 
                    retryLimit: 5,
                    minInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    maxInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    intervalDelta: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```csharp
  Retry.Except<BadException>().Immediate(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from Chris did not work for me for some reason. Maybe I was making this call from the wrong context. The only thing that worked was to make two UseRetry calls:

```csharp
configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(host, _config.QueueName, ec =>
{
    // Configure retries to immediately fail on permanent consumer faults
    ec.UseRetry(r => r.None().Handle<ConsumerPermanentFaultException>());

    // Configure all other retries as incremental
    ec.UseRetry(r =>
    {
        r.Incremental(_config.RetryCount, 
                      _config.RetryInterval, 
                      _config.RetryIntervalIncrement)
            .Ignore<ConsumerPermanentFaultException>();
    });

    // Load consumers from the container
    ec.LoadFrom(consumerContainer);
});
```